# Poisson Regression GLM in SAS

Tags: r, sas, regression, poisson

I'm attempting a Poisson Regression general linear model in SAS.

I'm an R user, so I have no idea how to do this stuff in SAS. I'll post the data, along with the code that I've attempted already:

```
  Game     Success     Attempts
  1        4             5 
  2        5             11
  3        5             14
  4        5             12
  5        2             7
  6        7             10
  7        6             14
  8        9             15
  9        4             12
 10        1              4
 11        13            27
 12        5             17
 13        6             12
 14        9              9
 15        7             12
 16        3             10
 17        8             12
 18        1              6
 19        18            39
 20        3             13
 21        10            17
 22        1              6 
 23        3             12
```

I've tried using several different codes on the data, but I keep getting errors.

This code doesn't work for the initial input:

```
options nocenter;

data freethrows;

input $attempt $success;

datalines;

...(this is where I put each attempt and success for each game in each row     for 23 rows)

;

run;
```

The example on the SAS website is the following:

```
data insure;

      input n c car$ age;

      ln = log(n);

      datalines;

   500   42  small  1

   1200  37  medium 1

   100    1  large  1

   400  101  small  2

   500   73  medium 2

   300   14  large  2

   ;

   run;
```

The GENMOD procedure is as follows:

```
proc genmod data=insure;

      class car age;

      model c = car age / dist   = poisson

                      link   = log

                      offset = ln;

   run;
```

I'd like to run a similar analysis on the freethrows.

Comment: At the moment your data does not seem to have a predictor variable. So it's rather unclear why you want to use regression. The exact correspondences are between 'Success' == 'c'   and  'Attempts' == 'n', so ti would seem to be simple matter to drop those in to the SAS code. The only remaining task is to figure out what SAS expects on the RHS for  NULL models. In R it would be the number '1'.

Answer (score 1):

Need to take out the dollar signs since those force a variable to be considered as "character" rather than numeric. Will use "Game" as the predictor variable. Try this:

```
data games;
  input Game Success Attempts;
  lnAtt = log(Attempts);
  datalines;
  1        4             5 
  2        5             11
  3        5             14
  4        5             12
  5        2             7
  6        7             10
  7        6             14
  8        9             15
  9        4             12
 10        1              4
 11        13            27
 12        5             17
 13        6             12
 14        9              9
 15        7             12
 16        3             10
 17        8             12
 18        1              6
 19        18            39
 20        3             13
 21        10            17
 22        1              6 
 23        3             12
;
run;
```

Then execute the PROC:

```
proc genmod data=games;
      #  remove unless you have categorical variables; class car age;
      model Success = Game  / dist   = poisson
                      link   = log
                      offset = lnAtt;
   run;
```

This should be a test of the effect of the "seasoning of player experience", or some such, on success, i.e a  a test of a linear trend in probability of 'Success' with increasing Game count. As a check against R's results:

```
    summary(glm(Success ~Game, offset=log(Attempts), family="poisson", data=games) )
#---------------------
Call:
glm(formula = Success ~ Game, family = "poisson", data = games, 
    offset = log(Attempts))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.1957  -0.7962  -0.2722   0.6774   2.1110  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.679572   0.189074  -3.594 0.000325 ***
Game        -0.008375   0.013544  -0.618 0.536346    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 18.778  on 22  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 18.396  on 21  degrees of freedom
AIC: 100.72

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

So the coefficient is near zero (where a positive value would have indicated an increasing probability of Success with increase in Game count), and there is really no statistical evidence of an upward trend.

Comment: I noticed on your proc genmod that the second line contains car and age. 

Which two variables from the freethrow dataset would I want to put there?

Comment: Ooops. That line should have been removed entirely. In SAS `class` variables are discrete categories and you don't have any of those. They are the SAS equivalent of "factors" in R.

Comment: Not to completely change the question, but I was wondering if I had a variable Y(i) that represented the number of free throws made for each game, with n(i) representing the total number of free throws attempted for each game (with Y(i) being binomial (n(i),pi(i)), how I would fit a model of pi(i) = alpha? I was able in R to find a value of .42 using R (which is apparently correct), but how would I find that value with SAS?

Comment: As I said once already: "The only remaining task is to figure out what SAS expects on the RHS for NULL models. In R it would be the number '1'."  My rather hazy memory that is now a couple of decades old was that in the past I have defined a new variable name `one` to which I assigned the value `1` and then use it on the RHS to get SAS to estimate a parameter for a NULL model.